# Регулярное выражение для URL на кириллице

Tags: php

```
static function isValidURL($url) {
    return preg_match('|^(http(s)?://)?[a-z0-9-]+\.(.[a-z0-9-]+)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
}
```

Как проверить URL на валидность (латиница и кириллица), чтобы соответствовал следующему шаблону: **example.com** или **пример.ком**?

Только **название(точка)домен**

Comment: Домена .ком вроде же не существует. Или я отстал от жизни?

Comment: это пример кириллического домена)

Comment: Так может быть, имеет смысл проверять именно существующие домены, а все прочие считать невалидными?

Comment: @Yaant Сколько новых доменных зон за прошлый год появилось на REG.RU? Много! К тому же url выступает в качестве адреса сайта пользователя, который находится у него в анкете. Поэтому ему нет смысла указывать нерабочий сайт.

Comment: А, я действительно отстал от жизни, вижу там и .ком тоже :) Однако, если пользователю "нет смысла указывать нерабочий сайт", то можно и вообще обойтись без валидации?

Comment: Нет, валидация нужна, чтобы в косметических целях отобразить, что это ссылка, а не текст. Пример этому ВК, в строке где должна быть ссылка на сайт..они пишут **у меня нет сайта** или что-то другое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *example.com или пример.ком*

```
static function isValidURL($url) {
    return (bool) preg_match('~^(?:https?://)?[^.]+\.\S{2,4}$~iu', $url);
}

var_dump( isValidURL('https://example.com') ); // bool(true)
var_dump( isValidURL('пример.ком') );         // bool(true)
```